# jQuery .animate() more efficient

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make this code more efficient, so I don't have to replicate it. I have 3 boxes with the mark up:

```
<div class="feature purple">
</div>

<div class="feature red">
</div>

<div class="feature blue">
</div>
```

And I am animating their contents, which I have ommited for less spam with:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.purple').hover(function() {

        $('.purple .icon').animate(
            { left: 220, opacity: 0.5 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
        });

        $('.purple .the-title').animate(
            { left: 15 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
        });

    });   
    $('.purple').mouseleave(function() {

        $('.purple .the-title').animate(
            { left: 75 }, {
            duration: 'slow',
            easing: 'easeInOutQuart'

        });
        $('.purple .icon').animate(
            { left: 5, opacity: 1 }, {
            duration: 'slow',
            easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
        });
    });              
});
```

How can I attach jQuery to '`.feature`' without the other 2 boxes animating, and lowering how many lines of jQuery I have to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of the code please?

Comment: provide a more complete html with necessary css

Comment: Thanks for your consideration but it's been answered below. Will post fiddle next time.

Comment: I don' think any additional HTML/CSS is needed at all. This question is more about the concept of referencing a specific object, when many object fit the selector of an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work just fine. Make sure you use `mouseover` instead of `hover` in that first binding.

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.feature').mouseover(function() {

        $(this).find('.icon').stop().animate(
            { left: 220, opacity: 0.5 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
        });

        $(this).find('.the-title').stop().animate(
            { left: 15 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
        });

    }).mouseleave(function() {

        $(this).find('.the-title').stop().animate(
            { left: 75 }, {
            duration: 'slow',
            easing: 'easeInOutQuart'

        });
        $(this).find('.icon').stop().animate(
            { left: 5, opacity: 1 }, {
            duration: 'slow',
            easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
        });
    });              
});
```

Comment: Remember, inside of any event, at the top level, `$(this)` refers to the object the event was called on. Happy coding.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I tried (this) but needed to .find. Also, any idea how I can animate the mouseleave quicker? if I hover out it takes 1s to callback.

Comment: The callback occurs after the animation is complete. Change `slow` to `medium` or `fast` to speed up the animation.

Comment: @SMacFadyen Animations are automatically chained.  To make the mouseleave fire when you leave, you need to stop the current animation.  The above example will only start to do the mouseleave animation *after* the mouseover animation completes.

Comment: Correct. You should add `stop()` before `animate()` like this: `$(this).find('.icon').stop().animate(...);` on all of your animations.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've used stop() effectively on the mouseleave function.